# Vim replace occurences of word with and without first capitalized in one S&R command

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

eg I have this peace of Java code

```
public String setType(String newType) {
  this.type = newType:
}
```

I select all of it and I would like to search and replace type by model, but regardless of the first letter, so that type is replaced with model and Type is replaced with Model:

```
public String setModel(String newModel) {
  this.model = newModel:
}
```

I cannot find a way to do this in vim with only one command, I tried those without success:

```
:'<.'>s/[tT]ype/[mM]odel/g
:'<.'>s/\(t\|T\)ype/\(m\|M\)odel/g
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [SmartCase](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1359):

```
:'<,'>s/type/\=SmartCase('model')/gi
```

Without a plugin, you also have to use `:help sub-replace-expr`:

```
:'<,'>s/\([tT]\)ype/\=submatch(1) ==# 't' ? 'model' : 'Model'/g
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it without a plugin?

Comment: @IamZesh: Yes, but it's tedious. See my edit.